# Why using MSE in Neural network despite it turns out to be non convex function

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, mean-square-error

I was going through articles of logistic regression and got to know that we dont use MSE because it will turn out to be non convex function ,but than why we use MSE in neural network?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I would say that the main reason we use cross-entropy in logistic regression is that it is in some sense a more natural or beautiful way to measure how well a predicted probability $q$ agrees with a ground truth probability $p$. For example, the cross-entropy loss function emerges automatically from the maximum likelihood estimation procedure. The fact that the optimization problem we solve to train a logistic regression model turns out to be convex is a fortunate side effect of our choice of the cross-entropy loss function, but it is not the most fundamental reason that we use cross-entropy.

Comment: It might clarify things for you to learn the statistical interpretations of linear and logistic regression, and to see how maximum likelihood estimation leads to the least squares loss function (in the case of linear regression) and also to the cross-entropy loss function (in the case of logistic regression).

Comment: Note that for classification problems we *do* typically use the cross-entropy loss function when training a neural network. Mean squared error is the standard cost function for regression problems (other choices are possible), and average cross-entropy is the standard cost function for classification problems.